# Correct way to pass git log contents with xarg & curl

Tags: git, command-line, xargs

I want to take the output of a git log and use it as an argument to the curl command.

Here's the git log command I'm executing:

```
git log -1 --format="(%h, %cn): %s"
```

The curl command:

```
curl http://www.example.com -F note='git_log_output'
```

Output for git log looks like:

```
(9b42b2f, Author Name): Adding support for fancy stuff
```

I thought xargs would do this but executing this (using echo instead of curl temporarily):

```
git log -1 --format="(%h, %cn): %s" | xargs -0 -I {} echo "Hi there {}"
```

It actually prints this:

```
27m" | xargs -0 -I {} echo "Hi {}"Hi (9b42b2f, Author Name): Adding support for fancy stuff
```

instead of:

```
Hi (9b42b2f, Author Name): Adding support for fancy stuff
```

What's a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` curl http://www.example.com -F note="`git log -1 --format="(%h, %cn): %s"`" ``

I think the backtick is what you want.